# Bootstro not working with bootstrap 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstro

I have the following codes

```
    <li><a href="#owner_leads" class="navbar-brand bootstro" data-bootstro-title="This is the Brand" data-bootstro-content="It is always visible" data-bootstro-placement="right"
       ><i class="icon-phone"></i><span
                        class="hidden-tablet"> Leads</span></a></li>

<li class="navbar-text navbar-right"><a href="#" class="navbar-link bootstro" id="guide">Guide</a></li>

$("#guide").click(function(){
            alert("I am clicked");
            // bootstro.set_bootstrap_version(2);
            bootstro.start(".bootstro", {
                onComplete : function(params)
                {
                    alert("Reached end of introduction with total " + (params.idx + 1)+ " slides");
                },
                onExit : function(params)
                {
                    alert("Introduction stopped at slide #" + (params.idx + 1));
                },
            });
        })
```

The problem is that when the guide button is clicked the page darkens on the tables are highlighted instead of the modal popup that was supposed to come.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap 2 are you running on? Bootstro.js supports Bootstrap 2.3.1 and up, so in case you have a bit older version, it may cause an issue.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 2.3.1

Comment: why is `bootstro.set_bootstrap_version(2);` commented?

Comment: I tried by uncommenting it. it still doesn't work